# Why doesn't bevel work on my object?

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I have made an object out of a cube, that I applied boolean and mirror modifiers. Now when I apply Bevel, I don't see anything. I want it to have slightly rounded edges and corners.

It doesn't seem to make any change if I disable the other modifiers or move Bevel higher up.

Here's what my object looks like:
[image]

It works on a cube, and here's what I want the edges to look like:

[image]

Here's my blend file:

[image]

Appreciate any help!

Comment: It's not working because of bad topology. You have there huge ngons.

Comment: Aha, is there any other way to round or fix the topology without modelling everything by hand? I assume it's the booleans that make this topology?

Comment: Yes it's Booleans fault (as usual). You could try to use Remesh modifier but it will probably create mesh so dense that Bevel will not work as well. Modeling by hand could by only way to use nice bevel. Maybe also you could try using Subsurface modeling. It's based on your modeling purpose.

Comment: Zoom very close and I found the Bevel is hapening but the Amount cannot be changed >0.00003 m. The other thing, not related to your problem here, Scale not applied, which also scaled the boolean.

Comment: Make sure the normals on your faces are all pointing the right way.  Boolean operators can sometimes leave you with faces pointing inside.

Answer (score 14):

Merge the vertices by distance and then it will work, just tested

Comment: Can you go into detail what precisely you need to do to do this, or why this works?

Comment: For future Google-ers in Blender 2.9: In Edit mode, select everything. Go to the menu in the top left corner of the viewport. and hit Mesh > Clean Up > Merge by Distance. This will remove any duplicated vertices. Which, for some reason, I ALWAYS end up having. I'm probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Oh Yea! Thats it

Answer (score 11):

I also came across this post. Turning off "clamp overlap" worked for me.

["Blender bevel modifier not working?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xx5W8hAYI0w) on YouTube and [transcript](https://web.archive.org/web/20201209074652/https://exposeacademy.com/blender-bevel-modifier-not-working/) (archived copy from Web Archive)

This was the relevant part of the post for me:

> We can force bevel modifier to bevel the edges even though there are double vertices in our model by turning off this “clamp overlap” option in here. Let me turn this modifier back on. Basically this option, if it is on, will prevent the modifier to produce bevel effect if the result will look bad because they will overlap. The overlapping happens because the existing gaps between edges are too small. Notice if we have this option turned off. And let’s put smaller width value like 2 mm. At the glance the model looks okay. But once we get close to this area, we can see this ugly result. So now we know why this option is turn on by default. It is to avoid us from having these ugly topology result. So essentially turning off this option is doable but it is not the best solution.

Subsequently the author describes how to avoid the problem in the first place should you want to read further.

Comment: Hi :) It would be helpful to add the essential information from the link in your answer. If it ever goes down, then your answer will then be a comment :) [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: I've added what works for me. There's a lot of good info in the post so don't want to copy it all here.

Comment: As the quoted text notes - turning off _Clamp Overlap_ isn't the best solution. If you watch the video the presenter explains why the problem occurs in the first place - overlapping edges (or in my case edges that were very close to each other which I'd actually created earlier with the Bevel tool - `ctrl-B` - rather than the modifier). Understanding how such edges constrain what the Bevel modifier allowed me to avoid the issue in the first place (i.e. don't create overlapping or very close edges if you're planning to use the Bevel modifier). There's further useful info in the video.

Answer (score 2):

Manually select edges you want to bevel. Press <kbd>W</kbd> and select *Bevel*. Press <kbd>T</kbd>  to open the *Tools* panel and on the bottom you will see different options for the bevel type.

Try selecting *Width*, it should work with your model type.

Answer (score 1):

I found running a limited dissolve on the model in edit mode fixes the topology problem left by booleans. Going back to object mode should reveal that your bevel modifier is having an effect.

Answer (score 1):

Bevel might not work in cases where the normals of the object is not correct. Recalculate normals with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Select the *Width Type* to *Absolute*, then the bevel works.